# Bootstrap - 100% Height Div Spilling over into Footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bare in mind, I am using Bootstrap3. Here's my basic markup:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row navigation"><!-- NAVIGATION GOES HERE--></div>
    <div class="container-fluid breadcrumb"><!-- BREADCRUMB GOES HERE--></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="content">
            <div class="col-sm-9" id="mainColumn">
                <p>Maecenas lacinia sed enim a porta. Nullam ultrices at neque congue vestibulum. In consectetur laoreet risus a laoreet. Aliquam varius urna in facilisis scelerisque. Nunc ut ante id odio mollis euismod laoreet et urna. Fusce consequat sem ex, in tristique urna sodales ac. Mauris feugiat rutrum erat, eget accumsan nibh ultricies sed. Vestibulum nibh nibh, viverra id imperdiet et, interdum sed dolor. Nullam tempor eleifend felis. Morbi vel tellus vitae odio venenatis venenatis. Suspendisse et euismod velit, sed scelerisque est. Vestibulum eget posuere ex. Morbi vulputate ipsum condimentum risus pretium, sit amet posuere nisi tincidunt. Donec cursus egestas ex eget blandit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="sideColumn">
                <p>Nulla est nisi, porttitor vel quam non, iaculis pulvinar nunc. Ut tempus fringilla justo, vel egestas libero vehicula vel. Mauris vitae tempor mauris. Nam aliquam elit in massa cursus, a dictum eros dictum. Aenean consectetur turpis a ante facilisis, quis porttitor est elementum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>FOOTER | FOOTER | FOOTER</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

footer{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #0000ff;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
}

p{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}

.navigation{
    height: 50px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

.breadcrumb{
    height: 25px;
    background: #00ff00;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #ffff00;
}

#content{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #00ffff;
}
```

It appears that the #content is spilling outside of the .container, and behind the footer, which I don't want. I want it to stop right at the bottom of the container, as you think it should.

I attempted to put an overflow:hidden on the #wrapper, but even though I have a height: 100%, rather than a height: XXXpx, the content gets cut off if the content is longer that the browser window. (I have this in place in the jsFiddle).

**THIS is what I am looking to do.**  Have the #content background end at the bottom of its .container, and not spill outside of the #wrapper.

***ADDED:*** ALSO, if the content is LESS than 100% of the browser window that the site remain the full height of the browser window

http://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/5k7xfvqn/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `height` of html/body to `min-height`

```
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

### [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5k7xfvqn/3/)

---

## Update

You can use `vh` to keep the entire screen filled even when the content is smaller than the screen (as you mentioned in your comment)

http://jsfiddle.net/5k7xfvqn/8/

The key is to change `min-height` and `height` from `100%` to `100vh`.
I changed `html/body` and `#wrapper`

`vh` means 'veritcal height' of the window.

Comment: FANTASTIC… but what if the content is less than 100% of the browser window? I switched it in my code, and it worked great, except the bottom of the site is quite exposed and naked.  I guess I should put that in my question, too.

Comment: exactly… I tried looking into a sticky footer, but centering an absolutely positioned element isn't an easy thing to do, especially if I want it to remain responsive.

Comment: I was still getting a white space between the content and the footer, but when I replaced height: 100% with height: 100vh on the container, all is well! Even in a collapsed and responsive format.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE9 and below, then you could try using CSS Flexbox:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MarkPlewis/hqkopoq5/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page title</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .container {
      -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    /* Non-essential styles */
    footer {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 5px;
      background: #0000ff;
      color: #fff;
    }
    p {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #wrapper {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .navigation {
      height: 50px;
      background: #ff0000;
    }
    .breadcrumb {
      height: 25px;
      background: #00ff00;
    }
    .container {
      background: #ffff00;
    }
    #content {
      background: #00ffff;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div class="navigation">NAVIGATION GOES HERE</div>
    <div class="breadcrumb">BREADCRUMB GOES HERE</div>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="content">
        <p>Integer feugiat condimentum eleifend. Nam eget ligula non neque elementum aliquam. Mauris interdum convallis ex id auctor. Donec consectetur pulvinar libero, ac tincidunt lorem hendrerit in. Donec eget fringilla neque. Etiam pulvinar, purus id dictum porttitor, magna eros sollicitudin lorem, vel auctor augue sapien ac nisl. Donec suscipit metus libero. Praesent hendrerit nunc libero, eu porttitor ante varius at. Suspendisse vehicula scelerisque erat nec facilisis. Donec efficitur tortor ac erat facilisis volutpat. Aenean in arcu semper, porttitor metus condimentum, condimentum dolor. Ut fringilla facilisis quam, eget rutrum ante. Praesent eu tincidunt mi. Maecenas vitae ex at neque tempus placerat id id neque.</p>
        <p>Vivamus bibendum est auctor ligula dignissim bibendum. Duis imperdiet condimentum lectus at varius. Nulla nec luctus velit, rhoncus tristique urna. Maecenas malesuada, libero ac semper ultrices, magna velit tempus massa, nec posuere nisi tortor vitae nisl. Etiam eu risus quis purus pretium euismod ac ac sem. Nam eu urna imperdiet, tristique eros et, porta nisi. Cras a lacus vel elit sollicitudin consectetur eget sed leo. Nullam porttitor scelerisque neque, eget lacinia justo venenatis congue. Nulla facilisi.</p>
        <p>Phasellus et nunc nec neque aliquam egestas. Donec turpis augue, suscipit ut auctor quis, volutpat in lectus. Donec a interdum metus. Etiam accumsan congue lacus sed elementum. Sed facilisis pellentesque convallis. Suspendisse lorem purus, consequat at ornare vitae, ornare ac lacus. Phasellus id orci eget ex aliquet condimentum quis viverra turpis.</p>
        <p>Cras vestibulum turpis a nisl egestas rutrum. Integer vel euismod neque. Pellentesque sed tellus et enim molestie ornare a vitae quam. Suspendisse dictum nisi id velit blandit facilisis. Nam quis enim est. Cras dignissim lacus sit amet ipsum aliquet, malesuada ornare nunc tempus. In rutrum, quam et blandit porta, massa tellus porttitor tellus, ac gravida nibh tellus non augue. Cras non augue finibus, lobortis odio quis, eleifend massa. Pellentesque fermentum sem ligula, a efficitur felis vestibulum non. Duis quis nulla porta, aliquam magna tempus, viverra urna.</p>
        <p>Maecenas sed odio nec nunc imperdiet rutrum non id mauris. Nulla vel aliquet erat. Duis dictum maximus nisi non scelerisque. Quisque elementum purus nec lacus tincidunt aliquam ac non libero. Ut consequat pulvinar finibus. Nulla tempus libero sit amet eleifend cursus. Fusce malesuada erat eget ante convallis, eu laoreet nisi laoreet. Nullam nec consequat augue. Quisque mattis diam tellus. Aliquam eget feugiat eros, non fringilla tellus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris sodales mi nec odio facilisis, non dignissim sapien vulputate.</p>
        <p>Nulla est nisi, porttitor vel quam non, iaculis pulvinar nunc. Ut tempus fringilla justo, vel egestas libero vehicula vel. Mauris vitae tempor mauris. Nam aliquam elit in massa cursus, a dictum eros dictum. Aenean consectetur turpis a ante facilisis, quis porttitor est elementum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>FOOTER | FOOTER | FOOTER</footer>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```